# <div>s not appearing inside one other div when they're suppose too

Tags: css, html

Basically I have a div, and inside that div is a wrapper and two other divs, one which floats left and one which floats right.

Here is what it looks like: http://puu.sh/Va3J

When you take a look at the code (listed below), you'll notice that .register-form and .login-form are both within #info, but they aren't appearing  that way for some reason

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/x8KaA/ (note I only put the code in a jsFiddle because it's a large chunk of code, the result in the result box is not how it actually looks)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What browser are you looking at it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make elements float, they don't affect the size of the parent element. You can use the `overflow` style to contain the elements, by setting overflow and not specifying height for the element, it will contain its children:

```
#info { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple fix, fixed my problem.

Comment: @Richie Be sure to check that in all the browsers you want to support :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is generally known and is fixed crossbrowser with clearfix:

[css clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)